# Block conversion in swift from Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, block

How to convert following block from `Objective-C` to `Swift`. Am using `Objective-C` files in `Swift` using `bridge header`. But small confusion in block conversion

**Objective-C Block:**

```
+ (void) while:(id)obj name:(void(^)(type*))callback;
```

**Sample output:**

```
[Sub while:keeper viewControllerChanged:^(NSString* newNickname) {
        NSLog(@"\nVC2- Now screen is in: %@", newNickname);
    }];
```

How to convert this in `swift` ?

**EDIT:**
Swift block error is

```
Sub.while(obj: AnyObject!, viewControllerChanged: ((String!) -> Void)!)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define :

```
class func while1(obj:AnyObject, callback name:((newNickname:NSString?) -> Void)) {


}
```

And when call function :

```
self.while1(self) { (newNickname) -> Void in

        print("\nVC2- Now screen is in:" + "\(newNickname)")
    }
```

EDIT :

Okay, Then you just want to call it from swift..right..? Then use this statement :

```
ClassName.while1(obj as AnyObject) { (nickName:String!) -> Void in

        print(nickName)
    }
```

But first make sure that in your definition statement "type" indicates for what DataType, so please define there actual DataType

```
+ (void)while:(id)obj name:(void(^)(type*))callback;
```

to --> For example :

```
+ (void)while1:(id)obj name:(void(^)(NSString *))callback;
```

And one more thing to note that `while` in built in keyword, please do not use it if possible.

Comment: am using objective-c class file. so i can't able to change black creation.

Comment: You can use `\`while\`` to use a keyword as an identifier.

Comment: @CuteAngel Thank you for your solution.

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks for your information about while keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You can call like this:

```
YourClassName.while2(Yourparameter , name: {(nickName : String) -> Void in

    })
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are asking how to write blocks in swift or if I'm not completely getting your question. But if it's the first then...

```
(void(^)(type*))callback
```

becomes

```
callback: (param:type*)->(returnType*)
```

i.e.

```
func doSomething(callback:((number:Int)->()))
```

is called like

```
doSomething(callback:{number in 
    print("\(number)")
})
```